# Moving ExpressJS API files onto Server

Tags: javascript, mongodb, api, express, server

So I created an simple API using **ExpressJS** that connects to **MongoDB** to perform **CRUD** operations. Currently I am able to get the local host running by performing command "**npm nodemon**" in the source folder. And it worked by testing with **postman** I wonder how to implement it on the server. As server runs a linux system, also I have a line of code in my  root file "server.js ":

`const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;`
I think the `process.env.port needs` need to be changed in order to make it work on the server?

In addition, I did look into aws CE2 server it is so complicated that I was immediately overwhelmed. I am  hoping someone can recommend dummy like me a simple and very specific solution to have a server run my scripts in ExpressJS environment. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your question is "How to deploy express app to a server?"

You can read some advanced topics on http://expressjs.com/, which covers some best practices, and other useful stuff. But the things you want to look at now is [Things to do in your environment / setup](http://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html#set-node_env-to-production)

The important part is:

1. Keep your express runing on port 5000
2. [Run your app in cluster](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html#run-your-app-in-a-cluster)
3. Run your app behind a proxy server like Nginx.

You can check this nice [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-20-04) (Step 3 and 4) on how to deploy your express app to a Linux server with PM2, Nginx.

So at the end, your express app will run on port 5000 (or whatever port you desire), and your Nginx will run on port 80, and nginx will forward any request to your express app.